# Build a circle inside the map in android

Tags: android, maps, geometry, marker

I want to build a circle with a specified radius on a map just like 
RadPad Apple application.

[image]

The idea is that the circle stays fixed but the user can move the map. 
inside the circle I want to count all the markers that are located inside its radius.

Comment: what have you tried? Do you have a map view you are working with already? Have you looked into how to draw a circle in a view?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but I'm working with maps so I can tell this: you must define in a map what "a circle" is. Because the map uses a projection so if you tells that a circle is the locus of points with the same distance from another point (center) it's not a perfect circle in a map. You must take in consideration projection type at first, and what distance do you intend as radius (great circle, rhumbline). You can see an example here: http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/23672142073/mercators-egg

Answer (score 0):

This works from me.

In xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Main.java

```
     public class Main extends ActionBarActivity{
        private GoogleMap gmap;
        private LatLng exact_location;

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.locations_layout);

            exact_location = new LatLng(LAT,LONG);
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            gmap = mapFragment.getMap();
            gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(exact_location,15));
            gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

           // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
            gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), null);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(exact_location)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(85)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

      gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
      CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(exact_location)
                                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                                     .radius(1000); // In meters
    gmap.addCircle(circleOptions);
  }
```